# Is Update Checking automatic for default?

Tags: 14.04, update-manager

In a freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04 when it is started and connected to the internet, does update manager automatically receives **the list of** updates ?

I want to turn it off if a the freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04 receives the list of updates automatically. btw, my main question is if it is on by default in a newly installed Ubuntu 14.04 and how to check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by default, Ubuntu Software center, fetches a list from the repositories you have stored.  I believe the default time is Daily.

To check this open up, system settings, Software and Updates.  From there you will see a window with multiple tabs.  click on the tab labeled `update`.  From there you can edit when Ubuntu fetches for the list of updates.

[image]

Also if you want to look at the list
`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`